# doubt on taking vertical pitch for dip packages

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I have one doubt on taking terminal row spacing from this below picture.
In this picture, which one have to take — eB or E?

[image]

Comment: Essentially this is a case where you should recognize the part as a standard variety from the "300 mil" in the description, and use a footprint with traditional 300-mil spacing rather than trying to interpret the *manufacturing detail* of the data sheet which shows what the manufacturer believes to be a suitable initial configuration for an IC that will fit on such a footprint. In a modern surface mount part you would pay more attention to detail, but those have less difference between manufactured shape and installed one, because the leads are either very short or mere metalizations.

Comment: To clear up your confusion for the dimension eB; the devices are shipped with the legs at an angle, and when loaded with a DIP insertion tool, the legs are straightened. The friction from the legs being pushed in holds it in position in the tool while being inserted into the PCB (whether by hand or automated)

Answer (score 2):

`Pitch` between pins in the row is 0.1 inch (2.54 mm);

Distance between the rows `E` is 0.3 inches (7.62 mm). That's why package is called "300 mil". There're DIP packages being called "600 mil" having 0.6 inches between the rows.

So to place this component onto your board (called footprint) you have 0.3 inches distance between the rows.

> why there is a dimension like eb?what it refers?

I think eB refers to the configuration of the [antistatic tube](http://www.spisemicon.com/ic-shipping-tubes/) to store chip in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help sir,but why there is a dimension like eb?what it refers?

Comment: ok sir ,now i want to take e for terminal row spacing is 310 mils am right?

Comment: `e` is pin pitch, and it is 0.1". `E` is row pitch and must be 0.3" on the board.

Comment: why it sholud be o.3?but they did not give value like 0.3

Comment: 0.31" is *nominal* distance between pins' rows where pins get out of the chip's body. Look at the picture - do you see where `E` is being measured? Distance between through hole pads on the board is different story, and it must be 0.3". Well, you can make it 0.31", but that is not usual, and chip socket will not fit if you will decide to put chip into the socket.

Answer (score 1):

The pitch of the component is 0.3" (7.62 mm).

The eB dimension is the "open" pitch of the pins. This allows easy pickup by a robot with a 0.3" 'gripper' which can be pushed down on the chip and squashing the pins together. The spring tension will keep the chip in the tool until pushed out. The pins will then go through the PCB and as they release will spring outwards and hold the chip in the board if it is inverted for soldering.

eB just tells you what the pitch of the pins is after manufacture. This may be important if, for example, the chips are fed from tubes into a machine with slots for the pins. The slots would have to be machined to the eB dimension.

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical manual IC insertion tool. Source: [Distrilec](https://www.distrelec.de/en/ic-insertion-tool-14-16-weller-dip-ic-14-16/p/18050182).*

Note that the sides are fixed at the nominal pitch (or a little over) so that when pushed down on the chip the pins will be parallel. When the button is pressed the white block (just visible between the jaws) ejects the chip. The pins should then splay outwards to hold the chip in the PCB.