# confusing on terminal row spacing

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

[image]see this picture given below, they are not given terminal row spacing then how to design land pattern for this dip package,and if they didn't given in datasheet how to take terminal row spacing from given values.
thanks for your help

Comment: Please highlight what dimension is missing. I see them all but you need to clarify what you mean.

Comment: You already asked this yesterday at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408917/doubt-on-taking-vertical-pitch-for-dip-packages and received comprehensive responses covering spacing in both axis and applicable to DIP IC's *in general* not just the specific data sheet you used as an example yesterday.   **DO NOT REPOST**.

Answer (score -1):

You have the dimension "E". You can make a larger mounting hole, or it is possible to move closer to the housing and the feet slightly incline inside.

Comment: This is not really correct.  As was explained when Hari asked this same question yesterday, the *standard* inter-row spacing of 300 mils should be used, the dimension given is that of the leads as shipped, not as installed.